# Implementing a button inside OnCreate();

Tags: android, android-layout

My question is that I would like to have a button display at the end of a string message that I generate from the main activity to another activity.

My main activity just has a button which when pressed displays that. I would like to have a button just under the message.

Someone told me to use the `OnCreate()` method. But its always giving errors and saying I am not giving the right input.

Comment: Can you show what have you done in your code?

Comment: you have to post the code and layout!